# preg_replace produces unexpected duplicate with a very simple RegEx

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
var_dump(
  preg_replace('/.?$/s', "x", 'abc'),
  preg_replace('/.$/s',  "x", 'abc')
);
```

Outputs:

```
string(4) "abxx" <-- strange, isn't it?
string(3) "abx"
```

How's that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace` replaces all matches in the string. So after doing each replacement, it searches for another match starting after the place where it made the previous replacement.

So it first looks for `/.?$/` and finds `c`, and replaces it with `x`, resulting in `abx`. Then, it looks again for `/.?$/` starting right after the `x`. Since `.?` means to match 0 or 1 characters, it matches the zero-length string at the end of the string, and replaces it with `x`. Then it stops because it has reached the end of the string.

Comment: I thought this way too, but according this logic it must go into an infinite loop. Because `.?$` acts like `.$` and `$`. Here `.$` is already beating last char, so if we _can_ run something after that, there is no reason to stop after `$`. Though probably it works like you said, but this is still looking like a bug.

Comment: I was wondering about that myself. I suspect there's a special check to avoid that loop.